# Regex - forbidding a certain string

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

So I'm new to regex and trying to write a regex that will match this:

```
example.com/some-url-text-here/
```

but not something like

```
example.com/some-url-text/but-also-more-than-two-slashes/
example.com/text-here/one-slash-too-many/two-slashes-too-many/
```

Basically, I would like it to match a url that has some `string-separated-by-dashes` surrounded by no more than two `/`'s.

I tried a couple of different things like [negative look around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952169/negative-look-ahead-python-regex) or [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688762/regex-to-match-2-level-deep-url-and-not-3-level-deep-google-analytics).... last thing I tried was this:

```
example\.com/[a-zA-z]*-*/
```

`[a-zA-z]*-*` matches something like `text-here`, but I can't get it to match `/text-here/`.. what am I doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your regex isn't working is because of the order you have it in.

```
example\.com/[a-zA-z]*-*/
```

This is looking for text UPPER and lower and THEN hyphens. Just include the hyphens in the brackets like so:

```
example\.com/[a-zA-z-]*/
```

Comment: Ohhh... that was a stupid mistake of mine. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

try regex below with [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), it will asserted no more backslash come after the 2nd

`example\.com\/[a-zA-Z-]+[a-zA-Z]\/(?!.*\/)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/9N2qVt/1)

Comment: Ah, thanks for showing how it works with the lookahead! For the above regex, I just put a `$` at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with regexen, you could simply [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) around `"/"`, make sure that the elements aren't empty (except possibly the last one) and that there aren't more than 3 elements.

You can use `-1` as parameter, to make sure the last elements are split:

```
>>> "some/url//".split("/", -1)
['some', 'url', '', '']
```

Comment: Didn't think of that approach, thanks for the answer!